# Authlogic: failed_login_count not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

I'm using Authlogic as the login system. Everything is working correctly except that it never updates the failed_login_count field when I purposely type in the wrong password. I am using the email as the login item. In the database there is no 'login' column. Is there something that I need to change or add to make this feature work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your User model valid? If it's not, the validation will fail and the column can't be saved.

Comment: Figure it out. In the User model the acts_as_authentic line had to be changed to this to force it to look at the email line.

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.login_field = 'email'
  end

Answer (score 1):

Remember: When you login, the `Failed_count_field` set to 0.

Comment: Not sure why you had the downvote. This is correct and not as we expected.